# UISplitViewController inside UITabbarController: master controller doesn't go under UITabbar

Tags: ios, ipad, uitabbarcontroller, uisplitviewcontroller

I read through few existing questions and tried setting "Under Opaque Bar" to no avail. [image]

See how the navigation bar and tabbar under master view is darker? This is plain Xcode7 new project with split view. The only thing added - UITabbarController.

What am I missing? 
[image]

**UPDATE**
Here is link to compressed project: https://dl.dropboxusercontent.com/u/6402890/dds1.zip

Comment: If I create a new project which mirrors yours, I do not see this darkening effect. I see a perfect white master and detail. The storyboard you have shown does not contain the Edit and + buttons, so I guess you must have added these either in code or the storyboard is not up to date in the question? I ran on iOS8.4 and iOS9 and all seems fine with xcode7 GM. Have you some code in the master view controller or have you set some color somewhere? You could try the 3D debugger view to see where the color is coming from?

Comment: @RoryMcKinnel, thank you for looking into it. I included link to the sample project. I haven't done anything about Edit/+ buttons - this code is part of default SplitViewController template. I have tried 3D debugger, but I could not find which frame is lesser then other.

Comment: Looks to be device specific. I tested on a range and some have the issue and some do not. Answer posted with fix.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This is quite an odd issue. Testing with your project, it seems to only affect iPad Air and iPad Air2 and iPhone 6+, not iPad Retina or iPad 2.

The issue relates to the setting of the UINavigationBar barTintColor and the UITabBar barTintColor.

You can fix your issue by doing the following:

1) For each UINavigationController, set the UINavigationBar `barTintColor` to white or deselect the `translucent` switch. You can do this in IB by selecting the navigation controller and then selecting the contained nav bar in the view hierarchy.

This deals with the top shadow.

2) For the UITabBarController, set the UITabBar `barTintColor` to white or deselect the `translucent` switch. You can do this in IB by selecting the tab bar  controller and then selecting the contained tab bar in the view hierarchy.

This deals with the bottom shadow.

---

When I set both to white it works. When I set both to be not translucent it works. Setting the color you want seems the best idea rather than changing the translucent setting.

As to why? Using the 3D viewer it looks like there is a long navigation bar style UIView which is 64 points high and grey which runs along the whole width of the split view controller. For whatever reason, on iPad Air and iPhone 6s, this is showing through. I guess it relates to the hardware acceleration or some other device specific feature in the newer devices.

**Update:**

Had another look, and the cause of the shadow is the background color of the UISplitViewController. You can not set this in IB it seems, but it looks like it has a grey color by default which is what you see showing through.

To fix this you need to create a class for the UISplitViewController and set the main views background color. Something like:

```
class MySplitViewController: UISplitViewController {

    override func viewDidLoad() {
        super.viewDidLoad()

        // Set the background color to white instead of default grey.
        self.view.backgroundColor=UIColor.whiteColor()
    }
}
```

So this seems the simplest solution.

Comment: So basically you're recommending to remove translucency and make navigation and tabbar white opaque. I tried that and it worked. I was really hoping for standard translucency work in this case - without UISplitViewController - it works just fine. Thank you for spending your time.

Comment: You can just set the color and leave translucency on as that works on its own. So I was recommending just setting the color and leaving translucency alone.

Comment: @sha Had another look and found a better solution. See updated answer.

Comment: Thank you. It worked, but it had a side affect of drawing separator line between master and detail in white color too. Do you know if there way to control that color separately?

Comment: @sha Apologies, never noticed the separator was gone. Looks like the separator is whatever the background color is as there is a 0.5pt gap between the left and right view controller frames! I guess you are back to setting the bar backgrounds or translucencies.

Answer (score 0):

Make sure that the master VC and its nav controller have their "under top bars" and "under bottom bars" checked, and that the table view's top/bottom constraints to supreview are relative to margins. Also make sure that the master view's background isn't dark or clear.

Comment: If only it would be that simple. UnderTop/Bottom are checked by default. There is no constraints for the tableView, since it's embedded into TableViewController and always occupies full controller frame. Not sure what you mean by master view background - but the only darkish background there (and the one that's visible) is one from UISplitViewController